# Runtime variable in serverless.yml isn't setting node version

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm running lambda functions on aws and deploying with Serverless. Updating node from 6.10 to 10.16, I updated nodejs with n, and changed the "runtime" line in the serverless.yml file to read:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.16
  stage: prod
  region: us-west-2
```

When I go to deploy with serverless, I get the following message:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: GetLaunchEventListLambdaFunction - The runtime 
parameter of nodejs6.10 is no longer supported for creating or updating 
AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime 
(nodejs10.x) while creating or updating functions. (Service: 
AWSLambdaInternal; >Status code: 400; Error Code: 
InvalidParameterValueException; Request >ID: abc26ccc-9289-431f-abd6- 
61a73bdb4c2e).

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           6.10.3
     Serverless Version:     1.27.3
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I had to go in the AWS console and change the runtime (node version) - then it would allow the cloudformation/serverless to update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be `runtime: nodejs10.x` but I came up here because I have the same problem even with (what I suppose to be) the correct syntax.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks. Did you get it working for you?

Comment: I also tried what Anatolii Bivol wrote in the comment but didn't work either. At the end I deleted the stack and re-deployed again